# How to add dynamic form on a button click in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am making a react app in which i need to add a form whenever button is clicked. Presently i am doing by increasing a counter and displaying the forms based on number in counter. But i need to submit all forms and get data on a single button click but i am having submit for each form and data of that particular form is gained.How to solve this??

This is how i am displaying forms:

```
var HocAddForm = function(AbstractComponent,title){
return class extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
    anotherForm:1
  }
  this.newForm=this.newForm.bind(this);
}
newForm(){
  this.setState({
    anotherForm:this.state.anotherForm+1
  })
}
displayForm(){
   let forms = [];
   for(let i = 0; i < this.state.anotherForm; i++){
     forms.push(
     <div key={i}>
         <AbstractComponent/>
     </div>
    )
   }
   console.log(this.state.value);
   return forms || null;
}

render() {
  const anotherForm=this.state.anotherForm;
  const heading=title;
  return(
    <div>
      <button id="add-button" onClick={this.newForm}>AddForm</button>
      <h3 className="form-place">{heading}</h3>
      {this.displayForm()}
    </div>
  )
}
}
}
```

My `AbstractComponent` is:

```
class Experiance extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Form onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit}>
                <fieldset disabled={this.props.disabled}>
                    <Input
                        type="text"
                        name="companyName"
                        title="Company Name"
                        value=""
                    />
                    <Input
                        type="number"
                        name="experiance"
                        title="No.of Years Worked"
                        value=""
                    />
                </fieldset>
                <button id="button-right">
                    {this.props.buttonName}
                </button>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with state in this case, keep your forms as an array of nodes, on Click add new component to array and then in render to the simple map on the array

pseudocode:

```
state = {
 forms: []
}

onClickMethod () => {
 this.setState(state=> state.forms.push(<Experience />))
}

render() {
 return (
  ...
  <form className="forms" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}> //your container
   this.state.forms.map(item => <item />)
  </form>
 )
}
```

Comment: The problem is i need to save all forms data with one submit button. i hope this approach wont do that..

Comment: then I would not keep them as separated forms, just fields groups, and one form as a container

Comment: you can assing key to every group and then in your logic (actionCreator with redux-thunk or redux saga) save your data :)